Error While Running dajngo project server through WSL

I am using Postgres as my db for this project.
My project directory is in my windows system.
Virtual environment was created in both windows and wsl (ubuntu) with all the dependencies.
Postgres-16 and pgadmmin4 are installed in my windows.
I was try to run the server from WSL2 (ubuntu) using python3 manage.py runserver.
Getting error in Exception in thread django-main-thread:.
connection to server at "localhost" (127.0.0.1), port 5432 failed: Connection refused Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?
port - 5432 is used by postgres for connection and i was unable to connect to postgres in my windows from WSL.
PSQL is installed in my WSL

psql --version
psql (PostgreSQL) 14.12 (Ubuntu 14.12-0ubuntu0.22.04.1)


I tried to add the subnets in my pg_hba.conf


# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             172.18.64.0/20          scram-sha-256
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            scram-sha-256
host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0            scram-sha-256


Double checked the listen_addresses = '*' in postgresql.conf
I tried to connect the WSL with postgers but get an error

 psql -h 'localhost' -U postgres -d encryptdata2
psql: error: connection to server at "localhost" (127.0.0.1), port 5432 failed: Connection refused
        Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?

